# Unable to set_password using POST request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to make a function which can reset user password of OTP matached to the stored value in user model.

I'm able to make a successful post request and JSON response I'm getting

```
{
    "detail": "Password have been changed"
}
```

But problem is password in actual dosent change but remains the older one.
Can anybody identify what is the problem in my function.
My API view is :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def reset_password(request):
    data = request.data
    email = data['email']
    otp_to_verify = data['otp']
    new_password = data['password']

    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        otp_to_verify == user.otp #user model has a field name otp
        if new_password != '':
            # user.set_password(make_password(data['password']))
            user.set_password((data['password'])) #changed to this but dosnt work 
            user.save()
            message = {
                'detail': 'Password have been changed'}
            return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            message = {
                'detail': 'Something wrong'}
            return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        message = {
            'detail': 'Something went wrong'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So I'm not sure what might be the problem as it's passing silently without giving any errors but in the end password does not change.

EDIT:
using this method user password hash in database gets changed but unable to login with new password and older password also gets invalid
this error comes then .

```
 Unauthorized: /api/v1/accounts/login/
    [11/Feb/2022 17:44:54] "POST /api/v1/accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 401 63
    Not Found: /jwt/refresh-token
    [11/Feb/2022 17:44:54] "POST /jwt/refresh-token HTTP/1.1" 404 2761
```

Comment: Are you supposed to use set_password and make_password together ?

Comment: i have changed to use just set_password call but it dosnt work

Answer (score 2):

I think that `user.set_password` method dont need to use `make_password` function.

1. `set_password` hash plain text password by default

   `user.set_password(data['password'])`
2. Using `make_password`

   `user.password = make_password(data['password'])`

Comment: But if i change this way it dosnt work either

Comment: Soo u use `user.set_password(data['password'])`, then `user.save()` and you can still login with PREVIOUS password ? Please make sure that your hash is changing in database.

Comment: let me check it again

Comment: yes hash gets changed but when it use new password to login it gives me Unauthorized: /api/v1/accounts/login/
[11/Feb/2022 17:44:54] "POST /api/v1/accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 401 63
Not Found: /jwt/refresh-token
[11/Feb/2022 17:44:54] "POST /jwt/refresh-token HTTP/1.1" 404 2761

Comment: Try to login in browser private window

Comment: same thing /jwt/refresh-token not found

Comment: I'm assuming doing this it dosnt update the other values like JWT in user database

Comment: Or should we have to change it to PUT request instead of POST so it dosnt update the other things in user model ???

Comment: Ofc it doesnt do it, your code only change password. I think that you have some auth jwt logic that is important in your code but i dont know how you implement this.